# Dynamic Azure public IP Address

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

In which scenario can we use a dynamic  public IP Address ? I cannot think of a scenario where i would want to expose a public IP  for internet facing azure services but that could be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

The two scenarios we use dynamic IPs are

1. A VM has a mechanism to auto update a DNS A record with its new address.
2. The Ip address has a CNAME mapped to the DNS name - so mapping `www.example.com` to `example.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com` This way whenever the address changes it still points to the same thing.

Remember though that a dynamic IP address doesn't change unless the VM is deallocated. Or the underlying host fails and VM is started on another host.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm

That outlines the use cases for both static and dynamic IPs.

The main use case for dynamic PIP's for me is for gateways. For web or app services I would use static.